# Is the name for Gruntfile configurable?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Is it necessary to have the name "Gruntfile.js" for the grunt file? Can it be given a different name and while running grunt specify the filename( Similar to a makefile in linux) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - I did a bit of googling and dug up this http://gruntjs.com/using-the-cli

So

```
grunt --gruntfile <some name>
```

Works

Comment: You could even have ran `grunt --help`